# Changing Header Colour on Scroll

Tags: java, html, css, header

I am using VS on a Mac. I've just started coding two days ago so I am a noob. I am trying to make a fixed header change colours on scroll although it is not working. I don't think it's a problem with my settings etc as when I ran it online the header didn't change from grey to black either.

```js
function changeRectangle() {
  const header = document.getElementById('header');
  var scrollValue = window.scrollY;
  if (scrollValue < 150) {
    header.classList.remove('header.active');
  } else {
    header.classList.add('header.active');
  }
  window.addEventListener('scroll', changeRectangle);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header.active {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 4;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.lowerbackground {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5000px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header" class="header"></div>
</body>

<script src="index.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="lowerbackground"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: and change `header.active` to just `active`

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your code syntax. Inside of the `.add()` and `.remove()` methods, you have to put the class name only.

Here is the correct syntax:

```js
header.classList.add('active');

header.classList.remove('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues

1. addEventListener inside the event handler
2. Too many body tags
3. You change the header.active, you just need to change active
4. You can toggle the active using the test, that is more elegant

```js
function changeRectangle() {
  const header = document.getElementById('header');
  var scrollValue = window.scrollY;
  header.textContent = scrollValue; // for visual testing
  header.classList.toggle('active',scrollValue >= 150);
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', changeRectangle);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header.active {
  background: #AA0000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 4;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.lowerbackground {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header" class="header">Header</div>
<div class="lowerbackground">Lower</div>
```

Suggested HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title is mandatory</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header" class="header"></div>
  <div class="lowerbackground"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably these actions will solve your issue.

1. First of all move  `window.addEventListener('scroll', changeRectangle);` out of function `changeRectangle`.
2. Secondly, `header.active` is not a valid  class name when is added to the DOM by JS. Rename it to `active` and change it in JS and CSS files accordingly.
3. Lastly, you have to set `!important` to background to give it high specificity
   to overwrite the background in `.header` class.

**HTML tips**:

1. `html` element is good to have `lang` attribute.
2. Here are two `body` elements, which is not good.
3. `head` element should have `title` element inside.

### Final code

```js
function changeRectangle() {
    const header = document.getElementById('header');
    var scrollValue = window.scrollY;
    if (scrollValue < 150) {
        header.classList.remove('active');
    } else {
        header.classList.add('active');
    }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', changeRectangle);
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.active {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 4;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    transition: all 1s;
    right: 0px;
    background-color: gray;
}

.lowerbackground {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5000px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>home</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="header" class="header"></div>
    <div class="lowerbackground"></div>
    </body>

    <script src="index.js"></script>

</html>
```